# Include or add HTML code inside leaflet rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, leaflet

I have a rectangle on my leaflet map, like this:

[image: like this]

```
L.rectangle([[51.53771659273237,-0.0418853759765625],[51.513793097655665,-0.16136169433593753]], {
    color:'red',
    fillColor:'transparent'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

I want to have HTML code inside this rectangle, like this:

[image: like this]

Comment: What is the L.rectangle().addTo(myMap). Is it from a library or what? Please edit your question to make it more detailed.

Comment: Is the rectangle supposed to behave like a `L.Rectangle` (position is geographical, size changes with zoom change), or is is supposed to behave like a `L.Popup`/`L.DivIcon` (stuck to **one** `L.LatLng`, size doesn't change with zoom change) ??